# VBA can't handle fields with #Value entered

Tags: vba, excel

I have a for each loop that gets tripped up when it comes to a field which has `#Value` entered.  I have a workaround because I kept getting `Ge0eral`, which I need to leave in place, but now I can't get past the fields with `#Value` entered.

Below is a sample table and code.

What I'd like it to do is print `#Value` or ignore the fields with `#Value` all together.

```
Sub TableMessup()
    Dim myTable As Range
    Set myTable = Range("A1:D3")

    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim tempstr As String

    For Each mycell In myTable
        tempstr = Format(mycell.Value, mycell.NumberFormat)

        If tempstr = "Ge0eral" Then
            Debug.Print mycell.Value
        Else
            Debug.Print Format(mycell.Value, mycell.NumberFormat)

        End If
    Next mycell


End Sub
```

```
+---+---+---------+--------+
| a | b |    c    |   d    |
+---+---+---------+--------+
| 1 | 4 | 5       | 50.00% |
| 2 | t | #VALUE! | 20.00% |
+---+---+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than making strings using *Format(),* use **Mycell.Text** instead of **Mycell.Value.**

Answer (score 2):

you can't print an error value, because it's not a string, it's an `error` type.

you can use the cell's `.Text` property, instead.

Or, you can use some conditional logic, like:

```
For Each mycell In myTable
    If IsError(myCell.Value) Then
        Debug.Print "Error at " & myCell.Address
    Else
        tempstr = Format(mycell.Value, mycell.NumberFormat)

        If tempstr = "Ge0eral" Then
            Debug.Print mycell.Value
        Else
            Debug.Print Format(mycell.Value, mycell.NumberFormat)
        End IF
    End If
Next mycell
```